# Elasticsearch-hadoop Connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, hadoop

I want to connect to an Elasticsearch [7.5] cluster with elasticsearch-hadoop using the SSL protocol. By providing the user and password with curl :

```
curl -XPUT -k -u "user:pass" https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com:9200/prefix-test
curl -XGET -k -u "user:pass" https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com:9200/prefix-test
```

I am able to create an index and get a response :

```
{"prefix-test":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1595854154818","number_of_shards":"1","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"k7Djh_fgHGIUTG76868Tuygi","version":{"created":"7050099"},"provided_name":"prefix-test"}}}}
```

Here "user" can only read or write to indexes prefixed by "prefix".

But when I try to connect to this cluster using elasticsearch-hadoop [7.5] with Spark [2.3.1] in Scala, with the following configuration :

```
"es.nodes": "xxxxxxxxxx.com"
"es.port": "9200",
"es.net.http.auth.user": "user"
"es.net.http.auth.pass": "password"
"es.net.ssl": "true"
"es.index.auto.create": "yes"
"es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed": "true"
"es.nodes.path.prefix": "/prefix"
```

Then I try to insert data with :

```
.saveToEs("prefix-test")
```

This give me :

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest:org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: index_not_found_exception: no such index [prefix]
```

And without the parameter "es.nodes.path.prefix": "/prefix" :

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest:org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: security_exception: action [cluster:monitor/main] is unauthorized for user [user]
```

What i am missing here ? How to use this prefix parameter ?

Could be relevant : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/spark-job-is-failing-with-authenticating-with-basic-error/25732/2

Comment: "es.nodes": "xxxxxxxxxxx" , try ginging  https:// or http://

Comment: "es.net.ssl": "false" and remove "es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed": "true"

Comment: https:// or http:// give the same reslut
"es.net.ssl": "false" : EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed

Comment: @bastienharmand might you have any update, i’m struggling with the same issue